# Using very long (10000+ characters) strings as SqlParameter value

Tags: .net, sql-server, string, ado.net

I am trying to execute an insert command into the database and one of the columns is of type nvarchar(MAX). Insert command is created by using .NET SqlCommand class and each of the parameters is represented by one SqlParameter object.

My command gets executed always, but when I pass string which length is large (10000+ characters) and which is used as a value for the SqlParameter mapped to the column of type nvarchar(MAX) after the insertion, that particular column is left empty. I repeat, no exception is thrown, INSERT command is executed, but column is empty.

Following examples are how I've tried to create parameter:

```
// message is the large string variable
// first solution
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@message", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);

// second solution
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@message", SqlDbType.NVarChar, message.Length);

// third solution
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@message", SqlDbType.NVarChar, message.Length * 2);
```

None of these solution gave result. If anyone knows what is the problem please tell me.

I am using MS SQL Server 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you setting the value? All I see is you creating a parameter, but no value is ever assigned.

Answer (score 5):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx)

> NVarChar:
>
> String. A variable-length stream of Unicode characters ranging between 1
> and 4,000  characters. Implicit conversion fails if the string is greater than 4,000 characters.
> Explicitly set the object when working with strings longer than 4,000  characters.

Here's ntext:

> String. A variable-length stream of
> Unicode data with a maximum length of
> 2 30 - 1 (or 1,073,741,823)
> characters.

also check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1904w6t%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: `ntext` is deprecated, so is `text` and `image`. `nvarchar(max)` replaces `ntext`

Comment: @Pierre: We're talking about SqlDbType (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=VS.80).aspx), which is on the client side. What you said is true only for the server side.

Comment: Worth pointing out that, after using this solution, SSMS may trick you into thinking an empty string has still been inserted, if you view the table in "Edit top 200 rows" mode. For me, it displayed an empty cell when the value was very long, although did show the shorter values, which made me think something still wasn't working - when in fact it was.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried calling `AddWithValue(String name, Object value)`?

Comment: +1 for noticing that he was creating a parameter, but not actually setting the value of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion to try: use `SqlDbType.NText` instead of `SqlDbType.NVarChar`.

Answer (score 0):

One Suggesstion.. Have you tried using SqlDbType.XML... There is no necessary to parse the xml in the other end... you can simply store the value in varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the problem if you explicitly create SqlParameter, like:

```
SqlParameter t = new SqlParameter("@" + name, type);
t.Value = value;
```

and then add it to parameters?

Also if you are invoking a sproc, just to make sure that sproc's param is also declared as nvarchar(max), or if you are not using a sproc try to use it. I've been pushing varbinary(max) blobs without any issues so maybe a binary gets better treatment.